# email mail field validation

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee

I am a newbie in Java EE and I wanted to know that which of the following will execute faster, Javascript or code written in servlet?

Context : Regular expression validation on email field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JavaScript` is `client side validation` so it will be faster. But if javascript are disabled in the browser it will not do the validations.

`Servlets` will be `server side validations`. It will be less faster but will be always better accurate in validation of fields.

Comment: I want to add the following: The client side validation is made to catch errors early and let the user correct it before submitting, **but you can never trust it, you must always validate it on the server side** because you have no control of what the user sends you. The [recommended](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#valid-e-mail-address) regex for javascript is currently (you can allow more but not less): /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/

Answer (score -1):

definitely javascript.
It's client  side validation and the browser itself can handle it. No need to go to the servlet.

Comment: The reason to downvote it the point you mentioned that there would be no requirement to take it to servlet level as the data can be manipulated before transmitting from client to server.